# Bypass blocked Snapchat on wireless

Tags: iphone

In our company they block Snapchat via wireless and we cannot use it. Is there a way to use Snapchat again on my iPhone?

Comment: Yes. Get the company to unblock it, or use your phone data instead of their wifi.

Comment: Buy a VPN and set it up on your phone.

Answer (score 2):

You can use mobile data which doesn't go through the Wi-Fi network.

If you still want to use the Wi-Fi and are not affected by the ramifications of accessing Snapchat on your work network, you can install a proxy, such as [Opera VPN](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/opera-vpn/id1080756781?mt=8&at=1001lwpF) or [Betternet](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/best-vpn-proxy-betternet/id946659216?mt=8&at=1001lwpF).